# How can I avoid traversing on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I see a recurrent "error" that actually I don't if it is an error or just some React regular behavior.

I am fetching some data from an API and then I am setting those values on some inputs.

So, see this example:

```
              <select
                value={
                  (startupFourthStepForm &&
                    startupFourthStepForm.my_team &&
                    startupFourthStepForm.my_team[index] &&
                    startupFourthStepForm.my_team[index].country_code_mobile)}
                required
                id="select-country"
                onChange={e =>
                  handleAddingNewObjectToFormArray(
                    e.currentTarget.value,
                    'country_code_mobile',
                    index,
                  )
                }
              >
                <option value="" className="empty-option">
                  Select Country Code
                </option>
                {COUNTRY_CODE_LIST.map(item => (
                  <option value={item.code} id={item.name} key={item.name}>
                    {item.name} {item.code}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
```

The question is regarding this piece of code:

```
value={
  (startupFourthStepForm &&
    startupFourthStepForm.my_team &&
    startupFourthStepForm.my_team[index] &&
    startupFourthStepForm.my_team[index].country_code_mobile)}
```

Every single time I want to render something coming an API, I need to do that kind of traversing. Otherwise I get an error.

Like if I do this
`value={startupFourthStepForm.my_team[index].country_code_mobile}` I get an error like `can not read property 0 of undefined` or stuff like that.

I am using lodash btw.

So, what kind I do to avoid that?

Comment: from what I understand your problem is not react specific you just want to access deep property without all the checks. For that you can use `lodash.get`. In your case it will be `_.get(startupFourthStepForm, 'my_team[' + index + '].country_code_mobile')`. You can also pass 3rd argument as a default value more info here https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#get

Comment: As @KarenGrigoryan mentioned, its not react issue rather javascript way of traversing the object. Alternatively you can wrap that code in a function call and then call that function where needed to make your component less ugly.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand your problem is not react specific, but you just want to access deep property without all the ugly conditionals.

For that, since you already use `lodash`, you can as well use `loadsh#get`.

It can go like:

```
const countryCodeMobile = _.get(startupFourthStepForm, `my_team[${index}].country_code_mobile`);

//...

value={countryCodeMobile}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a proposal for optional chaining in javascript which is available through babel:

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining

Basically you write your code like this:

```
startupFourthStepForm?.my_team?.[index]?.country_code_mobile
```